# Is there a continuous, surjective map from the unit disc to the unit circle?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Is there a **continuous**, **surjective**, map from the unit disc with boundary, in two dimensions
$$ D_ 1  = \{ (x , y) \mid x^ 2 + y ^ 2 \leq 1 \}  $$
to its boundary
$$ S_ 1 = \{ (x , y) \mid  x^ 2 + y ^2 = 1 \}? $$

I am having trouble figuring out what to do with the origin point. My first guess was the projection below, but it's not continuous.
$$ r e ^ { i \theta } \mapsto e ^ { i \theta} , r \neq 0, 0 \mapsto 1 $$

Comment: What about $f(x,y)=(1,0)$?

Comment: Apologies, I missed out the surjective condition in my question!

Comment: why is the polar projection not continuous? You have a problem at zero since it maps everywhere?

Comment: I'm no longer a university student. I'm on gardening leave and wanted to solve some puzzles :)

Comment: @gt6989b not continuous at $0$.

Comment: What about something like $f(x,y)=e^{\pi i x}$? Just a parametrization of the circle by the interval $[-1,1]$, you drop the $y$ value and ignore it completely? Maybe you're also missing a hypothesis in the question, that the map is constant on the boundary of the disk?

Comment: Squish the disk into a line segment, and then wrap the line segment around the circle. Unless you wanted the edge of the disk to stay fixed, in which case there isn't one.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that there is such a continuous surjection from the unit inerval, namely, $f:[0,1]\to S^1$ given by $f(x)=e^{2\pi i x}$. You can also find a continuous surjection $g:D_1\to [0,1]$, for instance, project onto the $X$-axis to get the interval $[-1,1]$, and then smash the left half of the interval onto the interval $[0,1]$.

Overall, this is a composition of continuous surjections, so it is a continuous surjection.

Edit: as said in the comments, you can make a more direct description by defining $f:[-1,1]\to S^1$ by $f(x)=e^{\pi i x}$, so you don't need to factor by $[0,1]$.

Comment: Thanks! I'm also just curious if there's a map which preserves the boundary, such that the restriction on the boundary is just the identity map.

Comment: @AfiqHatta No there isn't. See proposition 5.3.2 on page 237 here https://mtaylor.web.unc.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/16915/2018/04/analmv.pdf for a short proof of the smooth case. This is Brouwer's no-retraction theorem.

Comment: @AfiqHatta Mason has already answered your comment. Would you mind accepting my answer?